# PHP search in textfile then echoing it

Tags: php

I want to search for specific data in a text file which contains accentuated letters. I used this code:

```
<?php
    $file = 'textfile.txt';
    $searchfor = 'key';


    // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    // escape special characters in the query
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
    {
       echo utf8_encode(implode("\n", $matches[0]));
    }
    else
    {
       echo utf8_encode("No matches found");
    }
?>
```

But it's case sensitive and doesn't work with accentuaded letters.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks :)

Comment: use $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/mi" or pattern case insensitive

Comment: @Barmar this question has not duplicate as you said. There are some aspect which we have to consider while taking data from file_get_content. So please remove **duplicate** from this.

Comment: @Barmar I want to give answer for this question. But due to duplicate content i cannot post it there.

Comment: @Manish I've reopened. Although I think the only significant part of the question is the stuff that's duplicated.

Comment: @Barmar Thanx for re opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hiroo17 I explaining the method to do this.

Suppose you have `textfile.txt` file in which you have accentuated letters like below.

`Éric Cantona kÉy`.

Here is the below script to deal with **accentuated letters**.

```
$searchfor = 'key';
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
    $content = file_get_contents($fn);
    return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
    mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

function normalizeChars($s) {
    $replace = array(
    'ъ'=>'-', 'Ь'=>'-', 'Ъ'=>'-', 'ь'=>'-',
    'Ă'=>'A', 'Ą'=>'A', 'À'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'Ae',
    'Þ'=>'B',
    'Ć'=>'C', 'ץ'=>'C', 'Ç'=>'C',
    'È'=>'E', 'Ę'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E',
    'Ğ'=>'G',
    'İ'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Ì'=>'I',
    'Ł'=>'L',
    'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ń'=>'N',
    'Ø'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'Oe',
    'Ş'=>'S', 'Ś'=>'S', 'Ș'=>'S', 'Š'=>'S',
    'Ț'=>'T',
    'Ù'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'Ue',
    'Ý'=>'Y',
    'Ź'=>'Z', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'Ż'=>'Z',
    'â'=>'a', 'ǎ'=>'a', 'ą'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'ă'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'Ǎ'=>'a', 'а'=>'a', 'А'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'à'=>'a', 'א'=>'a', 'Ǻ'=>'a', 'Ā'=>'a', 'ǻ'=>'a', 'ā'=>'a', 'ä'=>'ae', 'æ'=>'ae', 'Ǽ'=>'ae', 'ǽ'=>'ae',
    'б'=>'b', 'ב'=>'b', 'Б'=>'b', 'þ'=>'b',
    'ĉ'=>'c', 'Ĉ'=>'c', 'Ċ'=>'c', 'ć'=>'c', 'ç'=>'c', 'ц'=>'c', 'צ'=>'c', 'ċ'=>'c', 'Ц'=>'c', 'Č'=>'c', 'č'=>'c', 'Ч'=>'ch', 'ч'=>'ch',
    'ד'=>'d', 'ď'=>'d', 'Đ'=>'d', 'Ď'=>'d', 'đ'=>'d', 'д'=>'d', 'Д'=>'D', 'ð'=>'d',
    'є'=>'e', 'ע'=>'e', 'е'=>'e', 'Е'=>'e', 'Ə'=>'e', 'ę'=>'e', 'ĕ'=>'e', 'ē'=>'e', 'Ē'=>'e', 'Ė'=>'e', 'ė'=>'e', 'ě'=>'e', 'Ě'=>'e', 'Є'=>'e', 'Ĕ'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ə'=>'e', 'è'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
    'ф'=>'f', 'ƒ'=>'f', 'Ф'=>'f',
    'ġ'=>'g', 'Ģ'=>'g', 'Ġ'=>'g', 'Ĝ'=>'g', 'Г'=>'g', 'г'=>'g', 'ĝ'=>'g', 'ğ'=>'g', 'ג'=>'g', 'Ґ'=>'g', 'ґ'=>'g', 'ģ'=>'g',
    'ח'=>'h', 'ħ'=>'h', 'Х'=>'h', 'Ħ'=>'h', 'Ĥ'=>'h', 'ĥ'=>'h', 'х'=>'h', 'ה'=>'h',
    'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'ì'=>'i', 'į'=>'i', 'ĭ'=>'i', 'ı'=>'i', 'Ĭ'=>'i', 'И'=>'i', 'ĩ'=>'i', 'ǐ'=>'i', 'Ĩ'=>'i', 'Ǐ'=>'i', 'и'=>'i', 'Į'=>'i', 'י'=>'i', 'Ї'=>'i', 'Ī'=>'i', 'І'=>'i', 'ї'=>'i', 'і'=>'i', 'ī'=>'i', 'ĳ'=>'ij', 'Ĳ'=>'ij',
    'й'=>'j', 'Й'=>'j', 'Ĵ'=>'j', 'ĵ'=>'j', 'я'=>'ja', 'Я'=>'ja', 'Э'=>'je', 'э'=>'je', 'ё'=>'jo', 'Ё'=>'jo', 'ю'=>'ju', 'Ю'=>'ju',
    'ĸ'=>'k', 'כ'=>'k', 'Ķ'=>'k', 'К'=>'k', 'к'=>'k', 'ķ'=>'k', 'ך'=>'k',
    'Ŀ'=>'l', 'ŀ'=>'l', 'Л'=>'l', 'ł'=>'l', 'ļ'=>'l', 'ĺ'=>'l', 'Ĺ'=>'l', 'Ļ'=>'l', 'л'=>'l', 'Ľ'=>'l', 'ľ'=>'l', 'ל'=>'l',
    'מ'=>'m', 'М'=>'m', 'ם'=>'m', 'м'=>'m',
    'ñ'=>'n', 'н'=>'n', 'Ņ'=>'n', 'ן'=>'n', 'ŋ'=>'n', 'נ'=>'n', 'Н'=>'n', 'ń'=>'n', 'Ŋ'=>'n', 'ņ'=>'n', 'ŉ'=>'n', 'Ň'=>'n', 'ň'=>'n',
    'о'=>'o', 'О'=>'o', 'ő'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'Ő'=>'o', 'ŏ'=>'o', 'Ŏ'=>'o', 'Ō'=>'o', 'ō'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ǿ'=>'o', 'ǒ'=>'o', 'ò'=>'o', 'Ǿ'=>'o', 'Ǒ'=>'o', 'ơ'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'Ơ'=>'o', 'œ'=>'oe', 'Œ'=>'oe', 'ö'=>'oe',
    'פ'=>'p', 'ף'=>'p', 'п'=>'p', 'П'=>'p',
    'ק'=>'q',
    'ŕ'=>'r', 'ř'=>'r', 'Ř'=>'r', 'ŗ'=>'r', 'Ŗ'=>'r', 'ר'=>'r', 'Ŕ'=>'r', 'Р'=>'r', 'р'=>'r',
    'ș'=>'s', 'с'=>'s', 'Ŝ'=>'s', 'š'=>'s', 'ś'=>'s', 'ס'=>'s', 'ş'=>'s', 'С'=>'s', 'ŝ'=>'s', 'Щ'=>'sch', 'щ'=>'sch', 'ш'=>'sh', 'Ш'=>'sh', 'ß'=>'ss',
    'т'=>'t', 'ט'=>'t', 'ŧ'=>'t', 'ת'=>'t', 'ť'=>'t', 'ţ'=>'t', 'Ţ'=>'t', 'Т'=>'t', 'ț'=>'t', 'Ŧ'=>'t', 'Ť'=>'t', '™'=>'tm',
    'ū'=>'u', 'у'=>'u', 'Ũ'=>'u', 'ũ'=>'u', 'Ư'=>'u', 'ư'=>'u', 'Ū'=>'u', 'Ǔ'=>'u', 'ų'=>'u', 'Ų'=>'u', 'ŭ'=>'u', 'Ŭ'=>'u', 'Ů'=>'u', 'ů'=>'u', 'ű'=>'u', 'Ű'=>'u', 'Ǖ'=>'u', 'ǔ'=>'u', 'Ǜ'=>'u', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'У'=>'u', 'ǚ'=>'u', 'ǜ'=>'u', 'Ǚ'=>'u', 'Ǘ'=>'u', 'ǖ'=>'u', 'ǘ'=>'u', 'ü'=>'ue',
    'в'=>'v', 'ו'=>'v', 'В'=>'v',
    'ש'=>'w', 'ŵ'=>'w', 'Ŵ'=>'w',
    'ы'=>'y', 'ŷ'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'Ÿ'=>'y', 'Ŷ'=>'y',
    'Ы'=>'y', 'ž'=>'z', 'З'=>'z', 'з'=>'z', 'ź'=>'z', 'ז'=>'z', 'ż'=>'z', 'ſ'=>'z', 'Ж'=>'zh', 'ж'=>'zh'
    );
    return  strtr($s, $replace);
}

$contents = file_get_contents_utf8($file);

$contents = normalizeChars($contents);

// escape special characters in the query

$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line

$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/mi";

    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
    {
        echo utf8_encode(implode("\n", $matches[0]));
    }
    else
    {
        echo utf8_encode("No matches found");
    }
```

Now i am explaining why i use the above method.
When you call file_get_content. it will destroy UTF8 encoding. For this either you can use the above **[mb_convert_encoding](http://mb_convert_encoding)** used in `file_get_contents_utf8` function or straightly use `utf8_encode` like `$contents = utf8_encode(file_get_contents_utf8($file));`

And then i use normalizeChars function to deal with **accentuated letters**.In that i use [**strtr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function whose main work is to Translate characters or replace substrings.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

And Thanx again @Barmar for reopening this question.I hope you will not disappoint with my answer.

Comment: @Hiroo17 Great. If It resolved, Please accept the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a i with your current pattern.

```
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/mi";
```

Comment: Thank you, now it isn't case sensitive but it still doesnt work with accentuaded letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get all the strings that contains accentuated letters.

```
preg_match_all("/\s+(.*?[ÇÜ]+.*?)\s+/i", $str, $matches);
```

[ÇÜ] is the range of chars between Ç and Ü

for more details about that range check the [ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/)